# Join two collection into one and get the single value from the array

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I join two collections? Let's say

First collection: Name

```
{
    "First_Name" : "Smith",
    "Last_Name": "Smiths"
}
```

Second collection: Information

```
{
    "Last_Name": "Smiths",
    "Address": "Some street"
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
db.Name.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
            from: "Information",
            localField: "Last_Name",
            foreignField: "Last_Name",
            as: "Without_array"
        }
}])
```

but I need the output to be

```
{
    "First_Name" : "Smith",
    "Last_Name": "Smiths",
    "Address": "Some street"
}
```

instead of the array that I get in the end, which I called `Without_array`.

Comment: You need `$project` stage with Address to get the first item of array: `Address: { $first: "$Without_array.Address" }`

Comment: The `$lookup`'s `as` field value is always an array. You need to transform the array data into a string field (as suggested in the above comment).

Comment: @YongShun and prasad_ and how to I combine the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you need a `$project` stage.

Take the first value of the `Without_array.Address` array via `$first`.

```
db.Name.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Information",
      localField: "Last_Name",
      foreignField: "Last_Name",
      as: "Without_array"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      First_Name: 1,
      Last_Name: 1,
      Address: {
        $first: "$Without_array.Address"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CNEZm0GXh28)